# How to Avoid implementing a POCO property only used for sorting feature of Telerik RadGrid at UI layer?

Tags: c#, sorting, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

All:

Here are the technical details pertaining to our Development environment for our Web Application:

- -Telerik version 2016.2.607.45

  -Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.35123.00 Update 2

  -.NET Framework 4.5

We are trying to integrate the Telerik “Grid - Excel-like Filtering” which can be seen by clicking on the following link:

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/excel-like-filtering/defaultcs.aspx

```
                                     <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="sampleGrid" runat="server"  PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" FilterType="HeaderContext"  AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu ="true"   EnableHeaderContextMenu="true"
 OnFilterCheckListItemsRequested="sampleGrid_FilterCheckListItemsRequested"     AllowSorting="true"  GroupingEnabled="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-    Bold="false"
                                         AllowPaging="true" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="0" Width="100%"
                                        GridLines="None" CssClass="RadGrid" DataKeyNames="ProductKey" EnableViewState="true"
                                        OnItemCreated="gvCommon_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="gvCommon_ItemCommand" OnNeedDataSource="gvCommon_NeedDataSource"
                                        OnItemDataBound="sampleGrid_ItemDataBound"
                                        EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"     EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="true">
                                        <MasterTableView Width="100%" 
                                        DataKeyNames="ProductKey" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItemStyle"
                                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRow"
                                        PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" PagerStyle-PageButtonCount="10" TableLayout="Fixed">
                                        <PagerTemplate>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="PagingPanel" CssClass="GridPagingPanel" runat="server" />
                                        </PagerTemplate>
                                        <Columns>
.................................................................
.........................................................
....................................
                                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn     ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItemStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"      AllowFiltering="true" EnableHeaderContextMenu="true"
                                                    HeaderStyle-Width="10%"      DataField="ProdDocumentStatusDescription"  FilterControlAltText="Filter     ProdDocStatus column" UniqueName="ProdDocStatus"     SortExpression="ProdDocumentStatusDescription">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label     ID="lblProdDocStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# LookupTypeConverter.GetDescription("ProdDocumentStatus", Eval("LatestDocument.DocumentStatus"), this.Language) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="clblProdDocStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# LanguageTranslationConverter.GetDescription("ProdDocStatus", Language) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
.................................................................
.........................................................
....................................
                                            </Columns>
                                        </MasterTableView>
                                     </telerik:RadGrid>
```

In our code-behind C# file, we have the following:

```
List<Product> prodList;
………………………………
…………………………
……………….
prodList =. ……..


sampleGrid.DataSource = prodList;
 sampleGrid.DataBind();
```

……………………………………………
……………………………………….
……………………………….

Our Product class is one of our POCOs.

Within our Product class, we have the following member:

public ProductDocument LatestDocument;

In turn, our ProductDocument POCO class has the following member variable:

public ProdDocumentStatus DocumentStatus

ProdDocumentStatus is an Enum with the following values:

```
public enum ProdDocumentStatus    {
    None = -1,
    NoStatus = 1,
    Complete = 2,
    InProcess = 3,
}
```

Therefore, our ultimate desire is that the user sees something like the following under the Product Document Status Description column when the page is displayed:

[image]

In order to get the Telerik “Grid - Excel-like Filtering” feature to work, we had to adopt the poor implementation practice of adding a property to the Product.cs POCO that is only needed for sorting to improve User Experience:

```
   public string ProdDocumentStatusDescription
    {
        get
        {
            string prodDocumentStatusDescription = String.Empty;

            if (this.LatestDocument != null) {
                switch (this.LatestDocument.DocumentStatus)
                {
                    case ProdDocumentStatus.None:
                        prodDocumentStatusDescription = String.Empty;
                        break;
                    case ProdDocumentStatus.NoStatus:
                        prodDocumentStatusDescription = "No Status";
                        break;
                    case CProdDocumentStatus.Complete:
                        prodDocumentStatusDescription = "Complete";
                        break;
                    case ProdDocumentStatus.InProcess:
                        prodDocumentStatusDescription = " InProcess";
                        break;
                }
            }
            return prodDocumentStatusDescription; 
        }
    }
```

At the UI layer, we have the following Telerik GridTemplateColumn with the SortExpression and DataField set to ProdDocumentStatusDescription:

```
                                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItemStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader"  AllowFiltering="true" EnableHeaderContextMenu="true"
                                                HeaderStyle-Width="10%"  DataField="ProdDocumentStatusDescription"  FilterControlAltText="Filter ProdDocStatus column" UniqueName="ProdDocStatus" SortExpression="ProdDocumentStatusDescription">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProdDocStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# LookupTypeConverter.GetDescription("ProdDocumentStatus", Eval("LatestDocument.DocumentStatus"), this.Language) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="clblProdDocStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# LanguageTranslationConverter.GetDescription("ProdDocStatus", Language) %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Could someone please tell me an alternative solution to the problem?  I really don’t want to create a property in a POCO that is only used for sorting purposes at the UI layer.  POCO should only contain core Business properties and members

Comment: Sounds like you may be overthinking it a little, extending data-defined classes like this is exactly how we use this kind of functionality at my workplace (which we use in implementing many RadGrids).  If you want a cleaner solution, move your "status description" functionality into the data layer in a view or something like that.

Comment: Would it be a good design to create a ProductView.cs class that corresponds to our Product.cs POCO where the ProductView.cs contains all viewable data that needs to be used in the View layer?

Comment: My advice is to worry less about "good design" and do something that works and is easy to maintain.  What you've proposed sounds like a good solution to me.